# A Chrome extension Error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, openai-api

This is a chrome Extension project that aims to produce summary and major points of a selected text on the web. I'm new to chrome extension development and trying to run this code. Any suggestion and help will be greatly valued.
**manifest.json file**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Text Summarizer and Major Points generator",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A Chrome extension that uses OpenAI API to summarize or produce major poinnts on the selected text.",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://*.openai.com/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
 
  "options_page": "options.html"
 
}
```

**Background.js file**

```
// background.js
// Generate a menu that gives an option for summary generation and major point generation
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'summarize',
    title: 'Summarize it',
    contexts: ['selection'],
  });

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'majorpoints',
    title: 'Major Point it',
    contexts: ['selection'],
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async function (info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId === 'summarize' || info.menuItemId === 'majorpoints') {
    // Inject the content script
    chrome.scripting.executeScript( { 
      target:{tabId: tab.id},
      function: fetchDataAndInteract,
      args: [info], 
    });
    }
  });
  

      async function fetchDataAndInteract (info) {

      chrome.storage.sync.get('openaiApiKey', async function (apiKeyData) {
        const apiKey = apiKeyData.openaiApiKey;

        if (!apiKey) {
          alert('Please set your OpenAI API key in the extension settings.');
          return;
        }
   
        const action = info.menuItemId;
        const selectedText = info.selectionText;
        const prompt = action === 'summarize' ? `Summarize: ${selectedText}` : `Write the major point of this post: ${selectedText}`;

        const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            prompt: prompt,
            max_tokens: 100,
            n: 1,
            stop: null,
            temperature: 0.3,
          }),
        });

        const resultData = await response.json();

        if (resultData.choices && resultData.choices.length > 0) {
          const resultText = resultData.choices[0].text.trim();
          const resultTitle = action === 'summarize' ? 'Summary:' : 'Major Points:';

          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            function: showResult,
            args: [resultTitle, resultText],
          });

        } else {
          console.error('No choices returned from API call.');
        }
      });
    }

    async function showResult(resultTitle, resultText) {
      const popup = document.createElement('div');
      popup.style.position = 'fixed';
      popup.style.top = '20%';
      popup.style.left = '50%';
      popup.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
      popup.style.zIndex = '9999';
      popup.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)';
      popup.style.padding = '20px';
      popup.style.borderRadius = '10px';
      popup.style.maxWidth = '80%';
      popup.style.textAlign = 'center';
      popup.style.fontFamily = 'Arial, sans-serif';
    
      const title = document.createElement('h3');
      title.innerText = resultTitle;
      title.style.marginBottom = '10px';
      popup.appendChild(title);
    
      const result = document.createElement('p');
      result.innerText = resultText;
      popup.appendChild(result);
    
      document.body.appendChild(popup);
    
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(popup);
      }, 10000);
    }
```

**content.js file**

```
//content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'showResult') {
    console.log('Message received in content.js:', request);
    const { resultTitle, resultText } = request;
    const popup = document.createElement('div');
  popup.style.position = 'fixed';
  popup.style.top = '20%';
  popup.style.left = '50%';
  popup.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
  popup.style.zIndex = '9999';
  popup.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)';
  popup.style.padding = '20px';
  popup.style.borderRadius = '10px';
  popup.style.maxWidth = '80%';
  popup.style.textAlign = 'center';
  popup.style.fontFamily = 'Arial, sans-serif';

  const title = document.createElement('h3');
  title.innerText = resultTitle;
  title.style.marginBottom = '10px';
  popup.appendChild(title);

  const result = document.createElement('p');
  result.innerText = resultText;
  popup.appendChild(result);

  document.body.appendChild(popup);

  setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.removeChild(popup);
  }, 10000);

    sendResponse({ success: true });
  } 
  // sendResponse({ success: true });
});
```

**popup.js file**

```
// popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function () {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'processText' }, async function (globalData) {
    const title = document.getElementById('title');
    const result = document.getElementById('result');

    if (globalData && (globalData.action === 'summarize' || globalData.action === 'majorpoints')) {
      const apiKey = globalData.apiKey;
      const selectedText = globalData.selectedText;
      const prompt = globalData.action === 'summarize' ? `Summarize: ${selectedText}` : `Major Points of: ${selectedText}`;

      title.textContent = globalData.action === 'summarize' ? 'Summary:' : 'Major Points:';
      result.textContent = 'Loading...';

      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            prompt: prompt,
            max_tokens: 50,
            n: 1,
            stop: null,
            temperature: 0.7,
          }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        const resultText = data.choices[0].text.trim();
        result.textContent = resultText;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching the summary/Major Point:', error);
        result.textContent = 'An error occurred. Please try again later.';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**popup.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3 id="title"></h3>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to convert from v2 to v3.
I am new to chrome extension development and trying to run this code. Any suggestion and help will be greatly valued.

Comment: If you create a msg, you need to have a listener.

Comment: 1) Use chrome.tabs.query + chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tab id in popup.js 2) You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension. 3) Extract fetch from fetchDataAndInteract and call it first, then send its result via executeScript's `args` . 4) Put showResult inside fetchDataAndInteract.